# Am I exporting my objects incorrectly? new to JS don't understand why test is failing

Tags: javascript, npm, jestjs, tdd

I am new to learning Javascript and my teacher is starting with objects and test driven development.

This is my code and the accompanying tests which are failing and I am not quite sure why. When I only had the first object and the first test it worked but when I added the second one it is failing.

Main:

```
const person1 = {name: "Louis"}
const person2 = {name: "Amber"}

module.exports = person1
module.exports = person2
```

Test Code:

```
const { TestScheduler } = require("jest")
const person1 = require('./family')
const person2 = require('./family')

describe('person objects', () => {
    test('I am in the family', () => {
        expect(person1.name).toEqual("Louis")
    })
    test('My sister is in the family', () => {
        expect(person2.name).toEqual("Amber")
    })
})
```

Test Outcome:

```
Debugger attached.
 FAIL  ./family.test.js
  person objects
    ✕ I am in the family (4 ms)
    ✓ My sister is in the family

  ● person objects › I am in the family

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "Louis"
    Received: "Amber"

       5 | describe('person objects', () => {
       6 |     test('I am in the family', () => {
    >  7 |         expect(person1.name).toEqual("Louis")
         |                              ^
       8 |     })
       9 |     test('My sister is in the family', () => {
      10 |         expect(person2.name).toEqual("Amber")

      at Object.<anonymous> (family.test.js:7:30)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.178 s
```

Comment: You are reassigning `module.exports` so the second assignment is overwritting the first, to export both put both into an object and export that, ie `module.exports = {person1,person2};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports = person1
module.exports = person2
```

module.exports is an object, so what you're doing above is assigning the object value to person1 and then overwriting the object value to person2, so Louis is gone.

If you want to export multiple variables, you would do:

```
module.exports = {
  person1: person1,
  person2: person2
}
```

Or if the object property name is the same as the variable name, you could shorten it as Patrick Evans stated in his answer:

```
module.exports = {
  person1,
  person2
}
```

You can also export using:

```
module.exports.person1 = person1
module.exports.person2 = person2
```

or shortened slightly to:

```
exports.person1 = person1
exports.person2 = person2
```

To do a named import, you would do:

```
const { person1, person2 } = require('./family')
```

You wouldn't need to change your test code otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment [@Patrick Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560593/patrick-evans), you just need to:

```js
module.exports = {
  person1,
  person2
};
```

Alternatively, you can export both variables like this:

```js
exports.person1 = person1;
exports.person2 = person2;
```

I think, generally there should be only 1 `module.exports = ...` statement in the file.